# Algebraic structures emerging from topologies

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, category-theory

this is a relatively broad question I will try to formulate it as clearly as possible.
If we are given a topology $\tau$ on a set $E$ and an algebraic structure on this set, we know we can make this structure "topological" in some way if we allow the continuity of the algebraic operations.

**My question is:** Is it possible to obtain algebraic structures by purely *topological* constructions? In other words, are there some topologies on a space that can allow us to recover some algebraic structures on that space?

EDIT: The question could be reformulated more precisely as: are there natural "algebraic" categories, with a faithful functor to the category of topological spaces which reflects isomorphisms

Comment: I guess a possible way to make your question precise would be to ask: are there natural "algebraic" categories, with a faithful functor to the category of topological spaces which reflects isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will add it to the question. I am not really acquainted with category theory so it was difficult for me to find some ground for precisely formulating the question.

Comment: It is not the case that, if we are given a topology and an algebraic structure, then we can make the structure "topological" by allowing something. Topological groups, for example, are groups whose underlying set is equipped with a topology such that the group operations are continuous: this is a **requirement** on the group structure given the topology. Given a topological group, we can't expect to recover the topology from the group structure: the group $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ is a topological group under many different topologies on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @CaptainLama I don't see how that's analogous to the original question. This is true of any topological-algebraic category, such as topological groups; I certainly wouldn't say we can recover a topological group structure by purely topological considerations.

Comment: The topology on $\Bbb R^2$ generated by the lexicographic (dictionary) order is shared by 2 ordered topological groups, one Abelian & one not. For $u=(x,y)$  and $u'=(x',y')$ in $\Bbb R^2$ let $u+u'=(x+x',y+y')$ and $u+^*u'=(x+x',y+y'e^x).$

Comment: @KevinCarlson I think this is due to conflicting terminology on "reflecting isomorphisms". I probably shouldn't have used that term. But it can mean that if $F(x)\simeq F(y)$ then $x\simeq y$ according to some authors (though I realize this is not the more common definition). And I think that is a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes, that makes more sense. I would really avoid that terminology choice without a definition, though, as you’re aware it’s a minority choice at best. Anyway; this “reflecting of an existence of an isomorphism” property is a bit special-I would rather just ask that the functor be fully faithful. That’s a common formalization of “a functor which forgets only properties.”

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I was wondering @RobArthan, should we at least have some topological equivalences or inclusions between the topologies of the set that make it into a topological group?

Comment: @KevinCarlson so the question could be reformulated as: are there natural algebraic categories, with a faithful functor to the category of topological spaces and this is still true if we take topological-algebraic categories? Also do you think my question still holds?